# StackOverflowException despite base case

Tags: java, algorithm

I am practicing an interview question where you want to return the shortest path from `beginWord` to `endWord` by changing one letter at a time and each new word must be in `wordList`.

```
Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from beginWord to endWord, such that:

Only one letter can be changed at a time
Each intermediate word must exist in the word list
For example,

Given:
beginWord = "hit"
endWord = "cog"
wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
As one shortest transformation is "hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog",
return its length 5.
```

I approach this using a dfs by getting the possible transformations for the current word (words that have only one letter difference) and recursing down each neighbor

```
public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, Set<String> wordList) {
        return this.dfs(beginWord, endWord, wordList, new ArrayList<String>()).size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> dfs(String curr, String endWord, Set<String> wordList, ArrayList<String> path)
    {
        path.add(curr);
        ArrayList<String> n = this.getNeighbors(curr, wordList);
        for(String w: n)
        {
            if(this.differsByOne(w, endWord))
            {
                path.add(w);
                path.add(endWord);
                return path;
            }
            this.dfs(w, endWord, wordList, path);
        }
        path.remove(path.size() - 1);
        return path;
    }

    public boolean differsByOne(String w1, String w2)
    {
        int diff = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            if(!(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(i)))
            {
                diff += 1;
            }
            if(diff > 1)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNeighbors(String beginWord, Set<String> wordList)
    {
        ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
        //int bwindex = 0;
        int windex = 0;
        for(String w: wordList)
        {
            if(!(beginWord.equals(w)) && this.differsByOne(beginWord, w))
                n.add(w);
        }
        return n;
    }
```

I am getting a StackOverflowException. This occurs when a base case is not hit, but I don't see why my base case `this.differsByOne(w, endWord)` would not be hit. (It fails in the above example) There has to be a word in `wordList` from which a transformation to `endWord` differs by one, so when that is found it should return.

EDIT:

Stopped StackOverflowException but getting wrong answer...

```
public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, Set<String> wordList) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> paths = this.dfs(beginWord, endWord, wordList, new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(), new HashMap<String, String>());
        int min = 1000000;
        for(ArrayList<String> n: paths)
        {
            if(n.size() < min)
                min = n.size();
        }
        return min;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> dfs(String curr, String endWord, Set<String> wordList, ArrayList<String> path, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> paths, HashMap<String, String> visited)
    {
        path.add(curr);
        visited.put(curr, curr);
        ArrayList<String> n = this.getNeighbors(curr, wordList, visited);
        for(String w: n)
        {
            if(this.differsByOne(w, endWord) || w.equals(endWord))
            {
                path.add(w);
                path.add(endWord);
                paths.add(path);
                return paths;
            }
            this.dfs(w, endWord, wordList, path, visited);
        }
        path.remove(path.size() - 1);
        visited.remove(curr);
        return paths;
    }

    public boolean differsByOne(String w1, String w2)
    {
        int diff = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            if(!(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(i)))
            {
                diff += 1;
            }
            if(diff > 1)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNeighbors(String beginWord, Set<String> wordList, HashMap<String, String> visited)
    {
        ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
        //int bwindex = 0;
        int windex = 0;
        for(String w: wordList)
        {
            if(!(beginWord.equals(w)) && this.differsByOne(beginWord, w) && !visited.containsKey(w)) {
                n.add(w);
                visited.put(w, w);
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a stopping condition within  your recursing method. Am I missing something?

Comment: If `differsByOne(w, endWord)`. So if the current word in the neighbor list can be turned into the end word by one transformation, add it to the path and return.

Comment: Have you run this with a debugger to see what in fact it's doing?

Comment: Completely shooting in the dark here, since I didn't check the code that thoroughly, but one possible way how you could end up with infinite recursion is if it loops between words that you already checked, for example `hit` -> `hot` -> `dot` -> `hot` -> `dot`...

You could put some console outputs into your code to see which words it actually processes.

Comment: I didn't look at your code yet, but it is possible to get a stack overflow because your recursion depth in a valid terminating algorithm is too deep.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool but I checked if the current word I'm recursing on is not the same as the current word in word list I am comparing

Comment: @JeremyFisher: You are checking the previous word, but does it also catch this loop, since it needs to look at all the possible neighbors?
`hit` -> `hot` -> `dot` -> `lot` -> `hot` -> `dot` -> `lot` -> `hot` -> ...

Comment: @Zhe I mean theoretically, but it shouldn't occur with the above example.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool You're right, for each recursive level, when getting the neighbors, I was checking the word I just came from. In other words, if I'm recursing on "dot", I just came from "hot", but "hot" is included in the neighbors. I fixed this with a `visited` map. Now I don't have the error but I just get the wrong answer. An improvement!

Comment: You get the wrong answer because you dont return the minimum path. You return some path that might not be optimal

Comment: @aviad let me update my code.

Comment: Unless you do something special, the max call depth is under 1000. With lots of options at every node, is it possible that you simply go deeper than 1000?

Comment: Perhaps, but the actual solution is a bfs, which should have the same depth.

Comment: The problem is probably now that you are using a single `visited` map for everything. You actually need a copy of the current one every time you go down one level, so the words you visit along one path are still eligible when you go down the path of another neighbor.

Comment: Actually, this whole problem seems like it could be solved with a Dijkstra algorithm if you build a graph network where each word is linked to the words it can be transformed into.

Comment: There's a number of problems here. First of all, the code you show doesn't actually compile. There's a few missing arguments and wrong return values with the path/paths objects. Second, you aren't actually cloning the path object when inserting into the paths lists, this means you will have a bunch of copies of the same path when the recursion ends. Third, your recursion style is really hard to understand for me, I advise a rewrite. I'll try to solve the problem myself and show you my code.

Comment: Have a solution here: http://pastebin.com/65zA1jmb. Let me know if you would like me to add comments. Also, don't pin me down that this actually works, but it seems to produce correct results. Please note that this code is not very neat, and should not serve as an indication of good code style.

Comment: All the words in word list will be unique, or duplicates can exist.